# Should I do database change inside each fetch request, or inside Promise.all?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I want to loop through the first 151 Pokemon using the PokeAPI, and adding each Pokemon to my mongo database.

I already have the schema for the pokemon, where I am just saving their string name, and an array of their moves.

I am looping through the axios calls, and storing them into an array of promises, and waiting for them to resolve

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const promises = []
 
    for (let i = 1; i <= 151; i++) {
        promises.push(axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`))
    }
    await Promise.all(promises).then(async (p) => {
        const newPokemon = new Pokemon({
            name: p.name,
            moves: p.moves,
        })

        await newPokemon.save()
    })

})
```

Is this at all correct? Where should I be doing my database queries, inside the individual axios calls or inside the promise.all?

Comment: This isn't correct. In your code, `p` will be an array of resolved values from all the axios calls.  So, `p.name` and `p.moves` will be `undefined` because `p` is an array of your values.

Answer (score 1):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns an array of values. You should use the [`insertMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-insertMany) function to insert all Pokemon at once:

```
await Promise.all(promises).then(async (pokemons) => {
    try {
        await Pokemon.insertMany(pokemons);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})
```